# Adding a onclick event to a table in blazor, with the table made by a for-loop

Tags: c#, html, onclick, blazor

So, I am using blazor to make an application. In the HTML part of a razor page I am making a table like this:

```
@for (int index = 1; index < amounts.Count; index++)
{
<table>
<tr>
    <td> @amounts[index] </td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

I need to add an @onclick event to each cell, the problem is that de arguments of that function are changing with the for loop.

So that means that if I do it like this (see below). Every cell will do onclick(amounts.Count) (Which is the last index of the table, the last value of index).

```
@for (int index = 1; index < amounts.Count; index++)
{
<table>
<tr>
    <td @onclick="()=>Redirect(index)"> @amounts[index] </td>
<tr>
</table>
}
```

I am not sure if I explained this enough and if my question is clear. Please let me know if it is not.

One solution might be that I get the rownumber of the cell. I have tried some things but I can not figure out how to get the rownumber if you make a table like this with a for-function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that value of index is gets "captured" in the lambda and when the function is invoked, the value of Index is always the same.  Find details [here](https://medium.com/swlh/the-magic-of-c-closures-9c6e3fff6ff9).

Change your code like this:

```
@for (int index = 1; index < amounts.Count; index++)
{
   int localVal = index;
<table>
<tr>
    <td @onclick="()=>Redirect(localVal)"> @amounts[index] </td>
<tr>
</table>
}
```

When you introduce a variable in the scope of the loop, the compiler will know to capture the value separately for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Awesome, I knew what the mistake was. But I did not know it was this easily fixable. Thanks a lot!